# Getting offset value in Carousel List

Tags: swift, swiftui

[image]I am trying create a Carousel list in which left to right scroll is working fine however I was unable to create right-to-left gesture, upon referring original tutorial I saw this was achieve by using this piece of code:

```
else {
self.x = value.location.x - self.screen  
}
```

I have no idea how this worked! I don't come from iOS/Mac background and my knowledge of CoreGraphics is limited. Any resource or link which explains about "location", "translation" and similar concepts in detail will be of big help. Thanks. Here is the full code:

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        
        @State var x : CGFloat = 0
        @State var screen = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 30
        var data = Card.all()
        
        
       var body: some View {
         
        
        NavigationView{
            
            HStack (spacing: 15){
               ForEach(data, id: \.id) { i in
               
               CardView(data: i)
                   .offset(x: self.x)
                   .highPriorityGesture(DragGesture()
                       .onChanged({ (value) in
                                 if value.translation.width > 0 {        
                                 self.x = value.location.x   //The "location" of the drag gesture's current event.      
                                 }
                                            
                                 else {
                                  self.x = value.location.x - self.screen
                                  print(x) //produces no output to console
                                       }    
                                       })
                                        .onEnded({ (value) in
                                            // code in process
                                        })
                )
            }
        } .navigationTitle("Menu")
          .background(Color.black.opacity(0.07).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
          .animation(.spring())
        }   
    }
    }
    
    
    struct CardView : View {
        
        var data : Card 
        var body : some View {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0){
                
                Image(data.img)
                .resizable()
                
                Text(data.name)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding(.vertical, 13)
                    .padding(.leading)
                
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 30, height: 460)
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(25)
        }
    }
    
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
```

and

**Card.swift**

```
[![import Foundation


struct Card : Identifiable {
    
    let id = UUID()
    var img : String
    var name : String
    var show : Bool
}

extension Card {
    static func all() -> [Card] {
        
        return [
          
            Card(img: "p1", name: "Black Coffee", show: false),
            Card(img: "p2", name: "Butter Garlic Chicken", show: false),
            Card(img: "p3", name: "Cappuchino", show: false),
            Card(img: "p4", name: "Chicken in Oyster Sauce", show: false),
            Card(img: "p5", name: "Orange Chicken", show: false),
            Card(img: "p6", name: "Kungpao Chicken", show: false),
            Card(img: "p7", name: "Burnt Garlic Chicken", show: false),
            Card(img: "p8", name: "Schezwan", show: false),
            Card(img: "p9", name: "Manchurian", show: false)

        ]
    }
}][1]][1]
```

Comment: Why you don't just wrap the `HStack` into a `ScrollView`? Then you don't have to apply a custom `Gesture`.

Comment: Thought about it but doesn't meet my requirement unfortunately